# python error: cannot import name historicData from iqfeed

Tags: python, unit-testing

I write the code as listed in the [readme.md of the iqfeed project](https://github.com/luketighe/IQFeed)

But get: `ImportError: cannot import name historicData`,
when I do `from iqfeed import historicData`

I have pip installed the iqfeed. (when in the myproject directory, but if I do pip install in the src or src/iqfeeder directories I get `up to date` messages so that's OK).

Python finds the iqfeed. (If I write `iqFeed` instead it says `ImportError: No module named iqFeed`

I'm running it from a `unittest` in ipython console in spyder.

my pythonpath is:
 - c:\python27\lib\packages
 - c:\dev\myproject
 - c:\dev\myproject\src\tests

- my class IqfeedImporter  using iqfeed is in `c:\dev\myproject\src\myfeeds\IqfeedImporter.py`
- my class IqfeedImporterTests with test_importfeed()  is in `c:\dev\myproject\src\tests\IqfeedImporterTests.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same project.

When you `pip install iqfeed` you get this package, not the one you linked.

https://github.com/tibkiss/iqfeed

If you want to use https://github.com/luketighe/IQFeed , just download it. It's just a single file called `iqfeed.py`.